# AMPscript error while testing saying I haven't ended an IF while looping IFs inside a FOR

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hey guys I'm developing a code where I need to loop 2 IFs inside a for but I'm getting an error saying I'm not closing my IFs.... although I have quadruple checked and I'm definitely closing my IFS, here's the code:

```
FOR @i=1 to @counter DO

IF Empty(@product6) THEN

 SET @row = Row(@rows,@i)
  
 SET @tipoR = Field(@row,"u_tipoarti__c")

 IF @tipoR != @tipoP THEN
 

  SET @FieldSet = TreatAsContent(CONCAT('%','%[SET   @product', @i, ' = Field(@row,"Product_Image_Link_c__c")]%', '%'))
  
  NEXT @i
  
  ELSE
  
  NEXT @i
  
  ENDIF
  
 ELSE
 
 SET @i = @counter
 
 ENDIF
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why so many _NEXT @i_ ? Hint hint.. :-) You are opening your code with FOR - so the last line should indeed be NEXT @i and not ENDIF

Comment: @LukasLunow tyvm for the help!

Comment: I have tried to clean up your Ampscript and post it as an answer, but to be honest I have failed to understand the business logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: @LukasLunow My honest issue here is I realized i need an autoincrement variable which for what I've been searching looks like it's not possible in AMPscript, am i right?

Comment: …did you try using @i? It is incrementing for each row. If not, your _next @i_ is not used correctly

Comment: The problem here is i need @i to be on max 6, but considering some rows might not be acceptable @i can be > 6